# Adicionar função ao firefox

Tags: html, xml, firefox, firefox-extensão

estou querendo fazer uma modificação no firefox de modo que ele atualize a página automaticamente após um período. Ou seja quero "acionar o f5" em um determinado intervalo de tempo e em uma determinada página. Andei lendo sobre extensões do firefox, e vi que elas são feitas em xml, mas n achei nada que me diga que eu possa mudar a estrutura do navegador apenas com essa linguagem. Que linguagem devo aprender para fazer essa alteração?

Grato!!!

Comment: Sabes que há um (vários na verdade) add-on para isso? https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/addon/reloadevery/